# Make api centric web application in java

Tags: java, api

I want to create one api-centric web application in java. I searched in internet and there is nothing about api-centric in java. Then I found that api-centric web applications are created in PHP. How can do this in java?

Comment: It would help if you could start by telling us what you mean by "api-centric".

Comment: yes. please check following link. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/creating-an-api-centric-web-application/

Comment: Okay, then I'd say most web apps (at least the ones I've worked on) are already API-centric. They just don't decide to start adding that as a name. Read any good tutorials on web app development, basically. As it stands, your question is too general to be answered specifically, IMO.

Comment: how can i make it in java? Means it has to applicable for anroid, windows, or symbion applications. not just in browsers. means is there any framework? i seen one framework that provides this type of functionality name is java FX (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX).

Answer (score 0):

If by API-Centric you mean something as mentioned [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/creating-an-api-centric-web-application/):

> An API-Centric Web Application is a web application that basically
>   executes most, if not, all its functionality through API calls. For
>   example, if you were to log in a user, you would send his credentials
>   to the API, and the API would return to you a result saying if the
>   user provided the correct user-password combination.

The closest thing which comes to mind would be to use the [Spring Framework](http://www.springsource.org/). You would still need to create your own logic, but you could expose this logic as an API through the use of beans, which you could call from your controller, so basically, you could do something like so:

```
...
if (loginService.loginClient(username, password))
{
    //redirect to home page
}

else
{
    //redirect to somewhere else
}
...
```

Comment: I think it doesn't have to do anything with Spring Framework. IMO, It's more of an architecture related thing than anything else.

Comment: @craftsman: What I mean was that in my opinion, the Spring Framework provides a structure way of building your own API and accessing it through the MVC framework. I do agree with you that most web development techniques are *API-Centric*, I just think that the spring framework makes things easier.

Comment: how can i make it in java? Means it has to applicable for anroid, windows, or symbion applications. not just in browsers. means is there any framework? i seen one framework that provides this type of functionality name is java FX (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX).

Comment: @kshitij: Take a look at tutorials such as [this one](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-tutorials/). This will put you on the right track. Spring will allow you to build a web application in java which can be accessed through any browser. If you want something to run on mobile platforms, then, I do not think you are looking for a web application, thus making your question misleading.

Comment: ok. i am saying that facebook is web application and i can access from  my laptop browser and i can access it from my windows mobile facebook application. as well as from anroid application.

Comment: @kshitij: You should be able to create a different servlet which caters for different URLs. You could have one servlet which deals wit the usual HTTP requests and another servlet which provides a REST web service interface which allows other applications to make use of your application.

Answer (score 0):

As quoted from the [article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/creating-an-api-centric-web-application/) referenced by the OP in his comment

> An API-Centric Web Application is a web application that basically
>   executes most, if not, all its functionality through API calls.

This describes every non-trivial web application. This may have been a relevant distinction 10-15 years ago when systems where more like isolated, self-contained "islands". Today, most if not all applications are built with interoperability in mind and the current architecture patterns all strive to build service/API oriented landscapes.

"API-centric" is, to me, moot.